# VB.NET how to remove image margin from DropDown list of a ToolStripDropDownButton

Tags: vb.net, windows-7

I am trying to remove the left-side margin, which is intended for image and check box of the DropDown list of a ToolStripDropDownButton.
[image]

This code does not help:

```
CType(ToolStripDropDownButton2.DropDown, ContextMenuStrip).ShowImageMargin = False
CType(ToolStripDropDownButton2.DropDown, ContextMenuStrip).ShowCheckMargin = False
```

Is there any way to achieve that?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more details, perhaps share some screenshots?

Comment: Hi. Neolisk. The margin I am trying to rid of is shown by red arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast is wrong, the Dropdown property is of type ToolStripDropDownMenu.  Just change the 2nd argument to CType.  The code in C# is:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        var dp = (ToolStripDropDownMenu)toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDown;
        dp.ShowCheckMargin = dp.ShowImageMargin = false;
    }
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Hans! Tanks a LOT! Works like a charm.